# Uniqueness of viscosity solutions of Hamilton-Jacobi equation

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, viscosity-solutions

Consider the following Hamilton-Jacobi (HJ) equation:
$$u_t + H(\nabla u,x) = 0 \quad \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \times (0, T], $$ where $u:\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$, and $H:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ (*Hamiltonian*) is continuous. 
Consider the initial condition $$u = g \quad \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \times \{t = 0\}.$$

In his textbook on *Partial Differential Equations* (pages 586-590), Evans proves uniqueness of viscosity solutions of this initial value problem under the following assumptions:
$$\vert H(p,x) - H(q,x) \vert \le C \vert p - q \vert;$$
$$\vert H(p,x) - H(p,y)\vert \le C \vert x-y \vert (1+\vert p \vert),$$ for some $C \ge 0.$ Evans' proof is relatively simple to follow, but slightly technical and, at least to me, not quite enlightening.

---

**Question:** Where can I find an alternative proof of this result?

---

**Side remark:** In [[CEL84]](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1984-282-02/S0002-9947-1984-0732102-X/S0002-9947-1984-0732102-X.pdf), Crandall, Lions, and Evans prove existence and uniqueness of viscosity solutions for a less general Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the book by Bardi and Capuzzo-Dolcetta:

"Optimal Control and Viscosity Solutions of Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman Equations" Bardi, Martino, Capuzzo-Dolcetta, Italo

Read the proofs for stationary equations $H(\nabla u, x) = 0$ on bounded domains first to get the main ideas. The proof in Evans has more bells and whistles to account for the unbounded domain.

I would also take the opportunity to plug my own notes (Section 6):

http://math.umn.edu/~jwcalder/222BS16/viscosity_solutions.pdf

Comment: Thanks; I'll have a look at that and then I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2):

The result (for slightly more general $H$) is [Theorem 3.15 p. 158](https://books.google.com/books?id=dyjrBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA158) in
the mentioned book by Bardi and Capuzzo-Dolcetta (it is a consequence of the Comparison Principle).